# How to get the ContextMenu Target in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3

in a flash application i have to build i would like to find out what the target of the context menu is, which gets displayed when i ctrl-click.
the reason for that: i created a custom context menu, which only displays over a certain area of the Sprite it belongs to. so there seems to be something "blocking the way".

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ContextMenuEvent.html#ContextMenuEvent()

to get the target of a ContextMenuEvent you want to access the mouseTarget property of that event.

Comment: Unfortunately he's not getting the event at all, that's exactly his problem. A non-descendant object is in the way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug this is using a click handler at the stage level.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stageClickHandler, true,
        int.MAX_VALUE, true);
```

Set `useCapture` to `true` so no other object can "swallow" the event, and `priority` to `int.MAX_VALUE` for good measure.

In your `stageClickHandler()`:

```
private function stageClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var targetObject:DisplayObject = event.target;

    trace("click target", targetObject);
}
```

Now click on the area that isn't displaying the context menu (when you expect it to), and see what is printed in the log file. You can do some inspection on `targetObject` by checking its `name` property, its `parent`, and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, and thanks. i alredy tried this approach though. however the result does not show a "blocking" item. maybe there is a bug with contextmenu? p.s.: out of interest why do you want to set the events priority to int.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: Hi, i found the problem. a loaded external swf is lying "on top" of the item with the custom context menu. and even though i set the "mousenabled" and" "mouseChildren" properties of that swf to false. i still cannot get the custom menu to register ... see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699988/custom-contextmenu-is-not-showing-since-display-object-is-lying-on-top

Comment: @blofeld Using `int.MAX_VALUE` to give the highest priority to the event handler (so no other handler is able to stop the event first). Was my answer useful to you in debugging your problem? If yes, then "upvote" or "accept" it, please.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at at the `contextMenuOwner` property of the `contextMenuEvent` ;)