# Custom ContextMenu is not showing, since Display Object is lying "on Top"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

as a follow up to another question here:
i've build a custom contextmenu item in a flash application and had a problem with it not showing sometimes.
i found out that the issue was that another sprite was lying "on top" of the item with the custom contextmenu.

however, even with the "mouseEnabled" and "mouseChildren" properties set to false for the item "on top" i still cannot get the custom contextmenu to show...
any ideas? thanks!

ps: here is some code to see the problem:

```
var spr:Sprite=new Sprite();
spr.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
spr.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
addChild(spr);

var blocker:Sprite=new Sprite();
blocker.x=50
blocker.y=50
blocker.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00,1);
blocker.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
addChild(blocker);
blocker.mouseEnabled=false
blocker.mouseChildren=false

var customContextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
var item:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("custom item");
customContextMenu.customItems.push(item);
item.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menuItemSelectHandler,false,0,true);
spr.contextMenu = customContextMenu;

function menuItemSelectHandler(cem:ContextMenuEvent) {
    trace("hello context");
};
```

when the mouse is over the green rect, the custom contextmenuitem is not shown

Comment: 1) some code will always help.   2) you have the sprite and context menu in the same layer ?  3) have you tried to set the childIndex of the contextMenu as the highest value in the children list ?

Comment: Hi, well to make it a bit more clear:
the custom contextmenu is not a sprite, but an item inside the normal context menu.
I added some code to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context menu for an object will be displayed only if the user right-clicks directly on that object itself, as far as I know.

I've simplified your problem in this code:

```
public class Test extends Sprite
{
    public function Test()
    {
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        addChild(sprite);

        sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        sprite.graphics.endFill();

        var shape:Shape = new Shape();
        addChild(shape);

        shape.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, .6);
        shape.graphics.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
        shape.graphics.endFill();

        setUpContextMenu(sprite);
    }

    private function setUpContextMenu(target:InteractiveObject):void
    {
        var menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        target.contextMenu = menu;

        var item:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("About Us");
        menu.customItems.push(item);
    }
}
```

When you right-click on the area where the red and blue squares overlap, you don't get the custom context menu.

Here's a possible solution, where I've modified only the `setUpContextMenu()` function:

```
    private function setUpContextMenu(target:InteractiveObject):void
    {
        var menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        this.contextMenu = menu;

        var item:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("About Us");

        var handler:Function = function (event:ContextMenuEvent):void {
            // Start with empty menu.
            var items:Array = [];

            if (event.mouseTarget == target) {
                // Directly right-clicked on target. Add custom item.
                items = [item];

            } else if (event.mouseTarget is DisplayObjectContainer) {
                var o:DisplayObjectContainer
                    = DisplayObjectContainer(event.mouseTarget);
                var pt:Point = o.localToGlobal(new Point(o.mouseX, o.mouseY));
                var arr:Array = o.getObjectsUnderPoint(pt);

                // One of the mouse target's descendants is our target,
                // directly under the pointer. Add custom item.
                if (arr.indexOf(target) != -1)
                    items = [item];
            }

            menu.customItems = items;
        };

        menu.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, handler);
    }
```

Here I'm assigning the context menu to the application itself. On the `"menuSelect"` event, I customize it based on whether the mouse pointer is somewhere above the red square.